# Devise only logs in when I select "remember me", and log out link doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

I have a new, playground-like Rails 4.2 application, and I just set up Devise on it, however I'm having some problems with the Session:

**TL;DR**: I'll try to resume it: Log out doesn't work, the server prints as if it's all correct, but user keeps logged in. Log in on production doesn't work, server also prints as if it's correct but I'm still getting 401s. Tried to log in in prod using "remember me" option, now I'm in but can't log out because of same bug. What is wrong?

By the way, this setup is working locally, at least for a single user, and apart from the time I had two users logged in at once (I explain it below), I can locally log in and log out without any apparent issues.

Now, the full story:

1. I'm using subdomain as a parameter for locale, so I get urls like en.sitename.com, pt.sitename.com, etc. One day, as I was testing Cancancan, I created another user and created some content for it. When I switched to another language, the app would switch to the first user, and when I switched back to the previous language it would also switch users.
2. When this happened I couldn't log out of either user. I clicked the `destroy_user_session_path` link, the server logged the delete action (and commit), it all appeared to have worked, but I always got redirected to the home screen, still logged to both users. I could only fix this clearing the browser's cookies.
3. After clearing the cookies, everything seemed to be back to normal, but now I deployed it to Heroku. I created a user, assigned the :admin role to it (I'm also starting to use rolify, but so far I basically only defined a role and checked if the user have it on `ability.rb`). Tried logging in, but the same "no-effect" thing that happened with log out is happening here too: I log in, but when devise redirects me to "/", I get a 401 and get redirected back to the log in. Tried it all, I even set cancancan to allow `can :manage, :all` to all users, but it would still give me a 401.
4. I tried to log in again, but this time selecting the "remember me" checkbox, and voila! I'm in, no 401s. But now I can't log out again, same issue as before.

I really don't know what in my code is wrong, so I'll try to summarize the important (to me) parts:

### `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # Have yet to configure this, but I'm not using emails with devise
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.reconfirmable = false
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.password_length = 6..96
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

### `app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  (... non-devise code ...)
end
```

### `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:change_language]
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, alert: exception.message
  end

  def index
  end

  (...)
end
```

### `app/models/ability.rb` (with temporary "allow-all" hack)

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

### I'm also redefining devise's views: (this is sessions/new, only relevant lines)

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name),
             html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'off', class: 'form-control' %>
  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <% end -%>
  <%= f.submit t('devise.views.login.submit'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

The gems versions are as follow:

- CanCanCan 1.12.0
- Devise 3.5.2
- Rails 4.2.4
- Rolify 4.1.1
- And running Ruby 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 (the more info the better, right?)

Comment: Check the browser console for javascript errors. The rail unobtrusive javascript driver (jquery-rails by default) fakes DELETE http requests by using AJAX. If there is a script error the request is instead sent as GET and devise won't log the user out. You can also configure devise to accept logouts via GET or [use a form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqnX8B1Y57k) if you need a no-js fallback.

Comment: I didn't check the javascript console, but the server is receiving the log out request correctly, as a DELETE, and the log in as a POST.

From the server: `Started DELETE "/users/sign_out"`

Comment: Also, the cookies may be specific per subdomain. So your cookie for `pt.sitename.com` may still point to a valid session while your `en.sitename.com` cookie does not.

Comment: The whole delete looks like this on the server: http://i.imgur.com/z9JFwtD.png

Comment: Yeah, about the subdomains, I haven't set these up on the domain yet, so I'm only using the default one (www I believe), and the location sets as 'en' by default.

Comment: I already briefly looked into this domain-specific cookie issue, but I didn't really did anything concrete yet to fix it, as I'm still ironing out some more important bugs, like this. I'm also not using Rolify at its full potential yet (read: I have no clue on how to use it properly), for the same reason, but I don't think these are the reasons to this issue.

Comment: Also you need to change your authentication hook so that it does not try to authorize the devise actions `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:change_language], unless:  :devise_controller?`.

Comment: Thank you, this seem to fix the log in issue, where I could only log in when choosing remember me, and apparently I can also log out. Tested in a new private tab, works, but my current login is still "locked" with me unable to log out. I'll try to let the session expire (I now set a 5 minute expire time to better test this), and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Yes, it seems correct now, thank you again! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Devise you need to exempt the Devise controllers from `before_action :authenticate_user!`. Otherwise the log in / out actions get stuck in a chicken vs egg conundrum.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:change_language], unless: :devise_controller?
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, alert: exception.message
  end

  def index
  end

  (...)
end
```

This applies to CanCanCan too as it will cause circular redirects:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  # ...
  check_authorization unless: :devise_controller?
  # ...
end
```

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Ensure-Authorization

Also you should move your "root" index action to a separate controller. This is because in most Rails applications `ApplicationController` is the superclass for all of your controllers. So you are effectively giving your all your controllers an index action. Many Rails apps use a `PagesController` or `HomeController` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the ApplicationController#index thing, never thought about that before.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue however, I don't have the `authenticate_user!` or any `cancancan` actions on the ApplicationController level. I later learned that overwriting `serialize_from_session` was what caused issues with both logging in and out. Hopefully this helps someone else on this search :)

Comment: This answer no longer applies as authenticate_resource! in Devise checks if it is a Devise controller.